# locales/en-US/translation.json loads in Eclipse but fail in iphone

Tags: android, ios, json, cordova

I am currently developing a cross platform mobile app using phonegap 2.5. When app starts it loads a json file for setting the app's language. It works perfectly in android but in ios it gets me that error: **failed loading: locales/el-GR/translation.json**. I tried to change the relative path for locales folder or move the current folder to other scope but neither seems to work.

**WWW subfolder path**

```
_www/
__index.html
__js/
___some js files like as main.js, cordova.js,jqmobi.min.js, i18next-1.7.1.min.js e.t.c.
__locales/
___en-US/
____translation.json
```

And the function i call in main.js:

```
i18n.init(
    {
        lng: AppSettings.Language.get(),
        fallbackLng: 'en-US',

        /* Where __lng__/__ns__.json = en-US/translation.json */
        resGetPath : '/locales/__lng__/__ns__.json', 
        resPostPath: '/locales/__lng__/__ns__.json',
        debug: true
    },
    function(){
    }
);
```

In main.js i give the relative url path for loading translation.json (locales/en-US/translation.json). This works fine in android but in ios it doesn't seem to load it.
So, if you can, i could need some help.

1. Does iphone understand differently the relative paths of a phonegap mobile app?
2. What path should i give so that the app loads the translation.json?

If you need more info tell me.

Ty in advance.